# Open email when the email icon is clicked in website

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am creating a website now and one part of it is when the mail icon is clicked. The email interface will display. I've seen example in internet like below:

[image]

When the email icon is clicked. The email interface will show:

[image]

What I want to do is to apply it in my website but I don't have any idea how it works. I am here to asked some suggestions or link tutorials on how to do it or if it's possible a sample code. I'm using php codeigniter. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to add one `<a>` link and point to email like:

```
<a href="mailto:myemail@site.com?Subject=Some%20subject"><img src="myImage.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: Okay you are right. What if I like to add a subject and content?

Comment: Also keep in mind, if the user doesn't have an email client nothing is going to pop up, or it might pop up an installed email client that the user doesn't even use to send/receive mail.

Comment: @Marko Thank you so much.